# Travis not starting jobs for multiple python versions

Tags: python, travis-ci

I have a travis job that looks like this:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: "Unit tests"
      language: python
      python:
        - "3.6"
        - "3.7"
      install:
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
      script:
        - python -m unittest test.client
```

I would expect this unit test to run two jobs one for python 3.6 and one for 3.7 however it always only runs for the first version listed. Am I missing something here? I followed the guide from [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/)

Thanks

Comment: Is it a public repo? Can you link to the travis builds?

Comment: https://travis-ci.com/semi-technologies/weaviate-python-client/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python versions are not defined within the jobs but on the root level.

```
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
jobs:
  ...
```

I found this out because travis recently introduced a build config validation. It can be found under *your build* -> **View config** -> **Build config validation**